# NID as a contextual filter doesn't work on some nodes

Tags: 7, views

I have a view where the NID is getting passed as a contextual filter for a specific content type, but some nodes doesn't pass at all and for some of them there is no problem.

I've checked the database, and I can see that the node NID I am trying to expose is there, but I still can't see it in Preview with contextual filters.

Comment: Are you sure those nodes (nids) belong to the specific content type? Are the any other filters, such as published = Yes? that could be filtering them out.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. And I can see the nodes in group view for particular node type when there is no contextual filter (http://sbch.org.mk/events-page). But when I click on link to view full node I can't see content, for some nodes (try last ones)

Comment: I see that the last 2 are duplicates, something weird is going on, and neither of them show anything on full node. When going to `/node/215` doesn't work either. Are you able to edit the node? `node/215/edit` ? is it filled out?

Comment: Yes I can edit the node. As a matter of fact I made the node with same content twice to checkout does it show the content with different NID (216).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I configured what was the problem. There were two referenced fields related with Relationship in view, and for those two relations I have checked the box "Require this relationship". So whenever I created content without any of those fields, content view was empty. When I unchecked  "Require this relationship" boxes, everything works good.
How ever thanks for your effords to help me.